# linux lines counting not working with python code

Tags: python

I am using WC -l to count number of lines in a text document. However I got a problem here.

I got a python code that wrote different combination of numbers into different files. each file contain each number of the combination on a separate line.

When I use wc -l for it, it didnt count the last line!

below is the python code:

```
import os
import itertools
lst = [6,7,8,9,12,19,20,21,23,24,26,27,28,29,43,44]
combs = []
for i in xrange(1, len(lst)+1):
els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]
combs.extend(els)
for combination in els:
  combination_as_strings = map(str, combination)
  filename = "_".join(combination_as_strings) + ".txt"
  filename = os.path.join("Features", filename)
  with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
     output_file.write("\n".join(combination_as_strings))
```

Thanks in advance,

Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `writelines`?

```
output_file.writelines(line+"\n" for line in combination_as_strings)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `join` you are using is placing newlines between lines, but not at the end of the last line. Hence, `wc` is not counting the last line (it counts the number of newlines).

Add `output_file.write("\n")` at the end of your script, in the `with` clause:

```
  with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
     output_file.write("\n".join(combination_as_strings))
     output_file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are seeing a variant of this:

```
$ printf '1\n2\n3' | wc -l
```

at the Bash prompt type this -- prints `2` because there is no final `\n`

Compare to:

```
$ printf '1\n2\n3\n' | wc -l
```

which prints 3 because of the final `\n`.

Python file methods do not append a `\n` to their output. To fix you code, either use [writelines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=writeline#file.writelines) like so:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(["\n".join(combination_as_strings),'\n'])
```

or print to the file:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
     print >>output_file, "\n".join(combination_as_strings)
```

or use a format template:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
     output_file.write("%s\n" % '\n'.join(combination_as_strings))
```

Comment: Many solution in one coment. I LOVE this thing :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `wc` command counts the number of new line characters in the file (`\n`).

So if you have 10 lines on a file, it'll return 9, because you will have 9 new line characters.

You could make it work as you want by adding an empty new line at the end of each file.